# JQuery Razor MVC Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue where the JQuery isn't firing on a button click. I've been looking through the Chrome debugger but nothing is coming up. No errors and when the button is clicked nothing happens.

I am using a fresh build of MVC with the initial references for Web API and MVC. The plugin I wish to get working is the Menu Slider [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Side-Menu-sidr.html)

I have tried to strip out as much as possible, the `sidr.js` and the `sidr.css` are the same as taken from the above link.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've reordered the scripts to get the `jquery-1.9.1.min` to load first but still no dice.

**Update**

I have just rebuilt the below code on another computer, same IIS, Visual Studio etc and it works (with the button) what could be making JQuery not run (I've gone through the references and they match up) as I'm out of ideas.

**Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.sidr.dark.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.sidr.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slide').sidr();
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="sidr">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="slide">Reveal Menu</button>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required:false)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want JQuery to do something on click try this. 
https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Here is a fiddler where Jquery pops an alert on button click.
https://jsfiddle.net/wncdr034/

Maybe you can trigger the slide from within the event function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this plugin needs to be instantiated on markup with a list inside. Something like this:

```
<a id="demo" href="#slide">Reveal Menu</a>
<div id="slide">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've managed to get this exact code working on another machine - didn't think Jquery required much, but must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

As per their documentation they have the below code:

```
<a id="demo" href="#sidr">Toogle menu</a> 
<div id="sidr"> 
    <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Side <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/">Menu</a> 1</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Side Menu 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Side Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

They have mentioned `href` to the `anchor` which is the `id` of sliding `div` but here you have button and have initialized `.sidr()` on that which will not have `href` attribute! I suspect the plugin may work on the `href` attribute of the `anchor`. So my suggestion is why don't you just replace your `button` with `anchor` and provide `href` value with the `div id` as below:

```
<div id="sidr">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
</div>
<a id="slide" href="#sidr">Reveal Menu</button>
```

Comment: Initially this is what I thought, but have recreated this on my other computer and it works just fine with the button, unsure what I'm missing but something's causing this not to fire.